# Angular $injector error loading the page

Tags: angularjs

I use AngularJS on my web app, and sometimes when I'm going to access a page of my application, The screen shows as below

[image]

And I get the following error:

[image]

This error rarely happens, and it's hard to simulate, most of the time the page loads normally. I already tried to use `ng-cloak` to prevent the page to load until all the elements are fully loaded, no success. The pointed error makes no sense because after the page refresh the error disappears.

Has anyone ever passed through this kind of error?

Comment: I have experienced this before, if I refresh it again after the error occours and it returns back to normal, I think you should take a look at the order of scripts JQuery first, angular second, etc. scripts should be provided in correct order.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
 
@NarenMurali The scripts are in the correct order, JQuery, Bootstrap, Angular, etc.

You said that you've experienced this error before, did you manage to solve it?

Comment: In development mode, if you include _angular.js_ intead of _angular.min.js_ the error is more descriptive

Comment: @FelipeNeves please try lealcelderio suggestion and post if a better error comes up, from my side I think you just need to take a standard angular template of the internet and check the definitions of ng-app, angular.module, etc.Just check if the syntax in angular is alright also the script tag for angular needs to be placed below all the other dependencies. 

do you know to which library this liteBooleanFilter belongs to, is this same error recurrent.

worst case scenario you need to remove the modules except angular and validate one by one which actually causes the issue.

Comment: Im going to try this. Thanks for your help, if i have any more issues im going to post it here.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

To hide the page contents until load. try this

CSS

```
// hide dom contents until page loads
[ng\:cloak],
[ng-cloak],
[data-ng-cloak],
[x-ng-cloak],
.ng-cloak,
.x-ng-cloak {
    display: none !important;
}
```

HTML

```
<body ng-controller="mainCtrl" ng-cloak></body> // element to hide until load
```

Comment: Im going to try this, if i have any more issues im going to post it here, thanks!